# Authentication with my android code for Twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to get a user tweets through this code:

```
public void displayTweets() throws TwitterException{

    /*loginToTwitter();
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
    */

     // Access Token
    String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    // Access Token Secret
    String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
    System.out.println("==> "+userID);

    try {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        //List<Status   > statuses = twitter.getRetweets(Long.parseLong(args[0]));
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getRetweets(userID);
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }
        System.out.println("done.");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get retweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

The problem is that I got the user id (for the system.out.println ("==>"+userID)), then I got a fatal error

> 06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:201)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1941)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getRetweets(TwitterImpl.java:209)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity.afficherTweets(MainActivity.java:287)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:418)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
>   06-26 15:31:35.983: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-26 15:32:02.513: I/Process(9874): Sending signal. PID: 9874 SIG: 9

What's wrong?

Comment: The reason is written here: `Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details`
Check where `PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN` and `PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET` are defined.

Comment: PFRE_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN and PREF_OAUTH_SECRET are defined in the begining of my application as this:

 **static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";**
 **static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";**

Comment: You must put your twitter app informations in these fields. Please register your app at this page : https://apps.twitter.com/